# Problems printing a directory listing to the console

Tags: java, printing, console

Sorry about readability. Stack appears to be trimming spaces from code lines & indents don't show up. Hrmph.

This was printing to the console without any problems...

```
CGT\whgdata\whnvp33.txt   << EXPECTED OUTPUT (excerpt)
CGT\whgdata\whnvt30.txt
CGT\whgdata\whnvt31.txt
CGT\whgdata\whnvt32.txt
CGT\whgdata\whnvt33.txt
CGT\whgdef.txt
CGT\whgdhtml.txt
CGT\whibody.txt
etc....
```

...until I tried printing the hashtable to a file. Since that point, `getFileListing` isn't recognized as a valid symbol.

```
FileListing2.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
        List<File> files = FileListing2.getFileListing(startingDirectory);
  symbol:   method getFileListing(File)
  location: class FileListing2
1 error
```

Can someone lend a second set of eyes to help me uncover what I accidentally/overwrote. I'm sure it's something obvious. :\

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.*;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
//
public final class FileListing2 {
    public static void main(String... aArgs) {
//
    File startingDirectory= new File("CGT");
    File outputFile = new File("CGTOutput.txt");
    List<File> files = FileListing2.getFileListing(startingDirectory);
    OutputStream output = null;
    //
    for(File file : files )        {
       System.out.println(file);  //print filenames
    }
}
}
```

Comment: There is no method called `getFileListing` in your class `FileListing2`?!

Comment: The snippet provided doesn't have getFileListing()

Comment: Well it DOES, I just had it commented out. Facepalm. Problem solved. Thanks.

Comment: @the downvoter: try this? http://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette which factual information in my post is incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code is all you have for `FileListing2`, than there is no `getFileListing()` method for `LileListing2`, only a `main()` method

Answer (score 2):

Yeah it IS something very obious, your class `FileListing2` does not contain a method `getFileListing(File)`. And it has to be static, the way you're trying to call it:

```
public final class FileListing2 {
    public static void main(String... aArgs) {
        //
        File startingDirectory= new File("CGT");
        File outputFile = new File("CGTOutput.txt");
        List<File> files = FileListing2.getFileListing(startingDirectory);
        OutputStream output = null;
        //
        for(File file : files ) {
            System.out.println(file);  //print filenames
        }
    }
    public static List<File> getFileListing(File f) {
    /* implementation */
    }
}
```